# Apache Tomcat stop one of two catalina files

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j, tomcat9

I have Apache Tomcat 9, not sure why I have two files with the name "catalina".

```
catalina.log
catalina.out
```

How can I disable the catalina.log file?

2nd question, I have another log file called "localhost_access_log.2022-08-05.txt" I want that to be in "localhost_access_log.txt" format without the date.

Please help me to achieve the above two queries.

I have Apache Tomcat 9 which is deployed in OS RHEL 7.9.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the Tomcat logging configuration. See the documentation at https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/logging.html.

Especially the **Considerations for production usage** at the end of the page mention:

*Consider removing ConsoleHandler from configuration. By default (thanks to the .handlers setting) logging goes both to a FileHandler and to a ConsoleHandler. The output of the latter one is usually captured into a file, such as catalina.out. Thus you end up with two copies of the same messages.*

The **access logging** is not configured with the Tomcat logging configuration but performed by the Access Log Valve. See [the documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging) how it can be configured.

Comment: Do you have any input on my 2nd question 'I have another log file called "localhost_access_log.2022-08-05.txt" I want that to be in "localhost_access_log.txt" format without the date.'

Comment: How can I remove the date from the file name, can you please guide me.

Comment: See the documentation that I referenced. Search for $CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml and do the necessary changes. Restart Tomcat.